# HTTP for deleting a resource

Tags: hl7-fhir

The [DSTU for REST delete](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/http.html#delete) is simple send, `DELETE [base]\[type]\[id]`.

However, what if the server implements [version aware updates](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/http.html#update)? Do I need to send a `Content-Location` HTTP header as well? As in:

```
DELETE ...\Patient\123
Content-Location: ...\Patient\123\_history\4
```

Or does the DELETE implicitly apply to the current version of the resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly makes sense to indicate which version you are expecting to delete, especially since you can still update a resource to "undelete" it, so we're talking multiple versions here. However, the definition of the Content-Location header states:

> The Content-Location entity-header field MAY be used to supply the
>   resource location for the entity enclosed in the message

and with a DELETE, we do not encode an entity. So, I wonder whether this is allowed. It's worth bringing this up for discussion on the HL7 FHIR site and/or gForge though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, and as you said in your question, FHIR do not imply with version-aware delete operations. In fact the DELETE operation only means that your resource will not be retrieved by SEARCH or READ operations. That said, given that your server implements a non-standard operation you could just answer to a DELETE request to a version url by deleting that specific version.

Let me say that, IMHO, alter the resource history is contrary to the philosophy that any change should be trackable. See http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/security.html#audit

Comment: I'm sorry, Re-reading your question I get that I may misunderstood it at first.
As I now understand I guess that you just want to know if the DELETE request must apply to the current version of the resource. The way we implemented it in our server is that we have a "Deleted" flag in each resource. When you send a DELETE request to a resource's url the server will write a new version of the resource with that flag set to true, so that a deletion is a logical operation which corresponds to a new version writing on underlying persistence layer.

Comment: Thanks @Origama, you are correct I'm only interested from the client perspective.  Does not the client need to include the version (Content-Location) when doing a delete to server that is version aware?